# Slider with Progress bar

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I develop an Windows Phone that play audio from the web, and i have Slider(normal) that show the progress of the audio Position .

And i want to add a something like progress of the audio buffer process .

Can i make the slider right(gray) to be invisible? 
There is any build control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar.aspx) class to add a progress bar to your
>   application. However, if you plan on adding an indeterminate progress
>   bar, using ProgressBar can decrease the performance of your
>   application. This is because the current implementation of ProgressBar
>   runs an indeterminate progress bar on the UI thread, rather than the
>   compositor thread. Instead, you can use the
>   CustomIndeterminateProgressBar sample to add an indeterminate progress
>   bar that runs on the compositor thread for better performance. This
>   topic describes how the sample works, and how you can use it to add an
>   indeterminate progress bar to your application.

Please see this [artice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg442303%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)
     
         
         
         
         
         
         
             
                 
                     
                         
                             
                             
                         
                         
                             
                                 
                                 
                                     
                                         
                                             
                                                 
                                                    Visible 
                                                 
                                             
                                         
                                         
                                             
                                                 
                                                    Collapsed